# Why my javascript file doesn't load?

Tags: javascript, html

This is the code of my html file:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="try1.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>

        <h1>A Web Page</h1>
        <p id="demo">A Paragraph</p>
        <button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

    </body>
</html>
```

And this is the code of my javascript file:

```
function myFunction() {
     document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Paragraph changed";
}
```

Comment: what do you mean it does not load.Did you check chrome developer tools and network tab of it.Did you find this js in that tab?

Comment: Is the `try1.js` file on the same folder with your HTML file?

Comment: Do not put parenthesis in onclick. it should be onclick="myFunction"

Comment: @Bill The above code works for me.

Comment: Hate to nitpick, but just a note: in general if you're only going to change the text of the element you should use `innerText` instead of `innerHTML`--it's a lot safer :)

Answer (score 4):

Because the element doesn't exist yet. Try putting the javascript at the end of the body

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Example<title>
    </head>
    <body>

        <h1>A Web Page</h1>
        <p id="demo">A Paragraph</p>
        <button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="try1.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

It seems to work just fine when inlining.

```html
   
        <h1>A Web Page</h1>
        <p id="demo">A Paragraph</p>
        <button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        function myFunction() {
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Paragraph changed";
        }
        </script>
```

Comment: The issue is not that. The code `document.getElementById("demo")` will run when the button will be clicked, and at that time the element will exist on DOM

Comment: @TasosK. exactly what I meant.

Comment: @TasosK. I see. Well I inlined the code and it works fine. So maybe your js file is not in the same directory as the html file.

Comment: @styfle It works with his code as well.The problem here is probably his JS file name is either incorrect or path is wrong.

Answer (score -1):

The usual way to do this is to wrap your javascript in jquery's document ready function like this. If you're not using jquery, you should check it out, it's really useful.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    console.log( "ready!" );
});
```

Comment: Why are you introducing another library here.Plain JS does the job.

Comment: There is nothing in this question that necessitates the use of jQuery

Comment: Not trying to start a holy war, but if you're not using jquery in this day and age, you really should be. If you don't, you have to worry about things like cross-browser compatibility and you end up reinventing the wheel.